# Derivative of Trace of matrix product

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, derivative

I am trying to compute the gradient with respect to a vector $\mathrm x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ of a complicated expression involving the trace of matrix product.

The expression is the following:
$$ F(\mathrm x) = \text{Tr}\left[ C \nabla (C^{-1} \mathrm f(\mathrm x))   \right],$$
where $C$ is a $d \times d$ matrix, and $\mathrm f(\mathrm x): \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ a vector valued function.

What I have until now is
$$ \nabla F(\mathrm x) = \nabla \text{Tr}\left[ C  (C^{-1} J_f(\mathrm x))   \right],$$

where with $J_f(\mathrm x)$ I denote the Jacobian of $\mathrm f$.
However I do not know how to proceed and take the gradient of the trace.
Would it be like this? $$\nabla \text{Tr}\left[ C  (C^{-1} J_f(\mathrm x))   \right] =  \text{Tr}\left[\nabla\left( C  (C^{-1} J_f(\mathrm x))   \right)\right]$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, your second equation is incorrect.

In index notation, the function $F$ is
$$\eqalign{
\def\n{\nabla}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\T{\operatorname{Tr}}
F &= C_{ij}\;\p_j(C_{ik}^{-1} f_k) \\
 &= C_{ij} C_{ik}^{-1}\;(\p_j f_k) \\
 &= C_{ij} C_{ik}^{-1}\:J_{jk} \\
 &= C_{ki}^{-T}C_{ij}\:J_{jk} \\
}$$
which can be expressed in terms of the trace in various ways
$$\eqalign{
F &= \T(C^{-T}C\:J) \\
 &= \T(J^TC^TC^{-1}) \\
}$$
But the *gradient* $\n F$ is
$$\eqalign{
\p_\ell F &= C_{ij} C_{ik}^{-1}\;(\partial_\ell J_{jk})
}$$
which doesn't have a simple trace expression.

The biggest obstacle is that the gradient is a ***vector***
while the trace is a ***scalar***.

$\sf NB\!:\:$ If $\,C=C^T$ then you can proceed as indicated
in [gunes answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/585419/210336)

Answer (score 2):

$CC^{-1}$ cancels each other in your second equation, you'll be left with
$$\nabla \text{Tr}[J_f(x)]=\nabla\left(\sum_{i=1}^d \frac{\partial f_i(x)}{\partial x_i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^d \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\nabla f_i(x)$$

Or $\nabla(\nabla\cdot f)$ in vector calculus.